# Google Apps Script failing on Slide.shapes

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to develop a Google App Script to modify a Presentation.
According to the doc, `Slide` has `pageElements` and `shapes`. I can access the first, but it fails with the second. Any idea?

I've tried this code with a basic google account, with a limited google workspace account (the old free version, without gmail access). Do I need a real google workspace to run this? And if so, why it is half-working?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide

```
function test() {
  const presentationId = '1PCnGJjxRUCuOvcMlTkP_Fs2R0TW0szokdpMZlEuaTHg'
  const presentation = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId);
  const slides = presentation.slides;
  console.log('The presentation contains %s slides:', slides.length);
  console.log('Contains %s pageElements.', slides[0].pageElements.length);
  console.log('Contains %s shapes.', slides[0].shapes.length);
}

The presentation contains 1 slides:
Contains 3 pageElements.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Answer (score 0):

About your error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` at `slides[0].shapes.length`, I think that the property of `shapes` is not included in the response value. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. When you want to confirm the shapes in the 1st slide, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
console.log('Contains %s shapes.', slides[0].shapes.length);
```

#### To:

```
console.log(slides[0].pageElements.map(({ shape }) => shape));
```

If the 1st page of Google Slide has no shapes, `slides[0].pageElements` returns undefined. In this case, the following modification might be able to be used.

```
console.log(slides[0].pageElements && slides[0].pageElements.map(({ shape }) => shape));
```

#### Note:

- By the way, the link ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide ) of your question is for Slides Service (SlidesApp). In your script, Slides API is used. So, you can see the official document of "[Method: presentations.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get)".
- From `the question is why slides[0].pageElements is working, and slides[0].shapes returns undefined.`, for example, did you want the following sample script?

  ```js
  function test() {
    const presentationId = '1PCnGJjxRUCuOvcMlTkP_Fs2R0TW0szokdpMZlEuaTHg';
    const presentation = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId);
    const slides = presentation.slides;
    console.log('The presentation contains %s slides:', slides.length);
    console.log('Contains %s pageElements.', slides[0].pageElements && slides[0].pageElements.length);
    console.log('Contains %s shapes.', slides[0].pageElements && slides[0].pageElements.reduce((ar, p) => {
      if (p.shape) {
        ar.push(p.shape);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []).length);
  ```

  ```js
  function test() {
    const presentationId = '1PCnGJjxRUCuOvcMlTkP_Fs2R0TW0szokdpMZlEuaTHg';
    const slides = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides();
    const pageElements = slides[0].getPageElements();
    const shapes = slides[0].getShapes();
    console.log('The presentation contains %s slides:', slides.length);
    console.log('Contains %s pageElements.', pageElements.length);
    console.log('Contains %s shapes.', shapes.length);
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Method: presentations.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get)

Comment: the question is why `slides[0].pageElements` is working, and `slides[0].shapes` returns undefined.

Comment: @David Portabella Thank you for replying. First, I apologize for my poor English skill. About `the question is why slides[0].pageElements is working, and slides[0].shapes returns undefined.`, the response value from `Slides.Presentations.get` includes a property of `slides` as an array. And, each element in an array `slides`, a property of `pageElements` (array) is included. But, no property of `shapes` is included. By this, `slides[0].shapes` returns undefined. On the other hand, `slides[0].pageElements` returns an array.

Comment: @David Portabella And, each element in the array `pageElements` includes the property of `shape`. So, I proposed the above modification. By the way, if the 1st page of Google Slide has no shapes, `slides[0].pageElements` returns undefined. Please be careful about this.
 If my answer was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: @David Portabella Now, from `the question is why slides[0].pageElements is working, and slides[0].shapes returns undefined.`, I added one more modified script by guessing your situation. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual expected result, I apologize again.